# Cron script not executing at correct time

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and am trying to execute a script each morning at 06:30am.

Using `sudo crontab -e` I've placed the following two lines

```
@reboot /home/ubuntu/download.sh
30 6 * * * /home/ubuntu/download.sh
```

I've also ensured that the `download.sh` script is executable with `sudo chmod +x download.sh`. The file returns green when I do an `ls` in that directory, indicating it's executable, I believe.

Here's the thing:

1. download.sh can be executed successfully with ./download.sh
2. @reboot is working
3. `30 6 * * * /home/ubuntu/download.sh` does not work

I've also tried `30 6 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/ubuntu/download.sh`, without success.

I've got the timezone set to my local, and using `date` confirms this, so I'm confident it should be executing at the right time compared to the time on my local clock.

So... Any thoughts are much appreciated

Comment: This question may be better suited for [ubuntu.se].

Comment: it might help you debug to have it run every minute or a test task which just prints something, and then you can be sure if it is firing or not. Every minute = `* * * * *` (https://crontab.guru/). I don't know how you debug crontasks, but seems to me you need some cron monitoring or some way to be absolutely sure if it is firing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th cron script needed to have precisely one blank line at the end. No spaces, no nothing. Just a single blank line.